# coarsening of merge sort

Tags: algorithm, mergesort, clrs

I just started CLRS. The first problem of the 2nd chapter involves coarsening the merge sort algorithm by using insertion sort when the subarray reaches a specified minimum size. I have written the modified code and i think it is correct as I have checked it on some inputs and different values of *coarseness*. I am not so sure about some hidden corner cases.
Can anybody tell me if it can be improvised further. 
Here is the modified merge sort procedure(its run time in theta notation is (nk + nlg(n/k)):

```
void mergesort(int arr[], int p, int r, int k) { // k is the coarseness
    int q = (p + r) / 2;

    if (r - p + 1 > k) { // when the size of the subarray is atmost k, sort using insertion sort
    mergesort(arr, p, q, k);
    mergesort(arr, q + 1, r, k);

        merge(arr, p, q, r); // merge is the standard procedure

    }
    else {
        insort(arr, p, r); // insort is the standard insertion sort procedure
    }

}
```

Moreover part 3 of the question asks the largest value of k at which the run time of this procedure is same as the standard mergesort algorithm. I tried equating the theta notations of both the procedures(nk + nlg(n/k) = nlgn) , but can that be done? is it valid to do that since i am not getting a sensible answer. Any sort of help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In this case, the run time is probably the actual run time on your computer. If you try theta calculations, it won't take into account that insertion sort on a small number of elements will be operating within the cache on a processor.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. That clears it. So what should be my approach if I want to solve this question?

Comment: I'm not sure what implementation is suggested in the CLRS book, but generally the code should do a one time allocation of the temporary array, then merge back and forth between the two arrays. The [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) includes some example pseudo-code. You'll need to test with 16 million integers or so to compare times. k doens't need to be passed as a parameter, as it is a constant. The break even value for k is probably between 64 and 192.